# KSS styleguides generator for Rails - alternatives to NKSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

What KSS style generator do you guys use for Rails? I tried with NKSS but I don't quite like it (maybe because I'm not used to document CSS yet).

Anyone of you knows what [Github](https://github.com/styleguide/css) uses?

Comment: Github uses vanilla KSS I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I have found https://github.com/dewski/kss-rails also. I never documented my CSS but you can give a try.